# DPI scaling a complete dialog box from resource

Tags: winapi, dialog, controls, dpi

I setup per-monitor DPI scaling in a Win32 app, and my part works fine, however opening up a dialog box created in the resource editor doesn't scale itself (I would think using dialog units, it would).

Is there a way to scale everything from a dialog resource and be compatible with, say, Win8.1, as well as Win10, and even Win7?

Comment: At least with Windows 10 (1703 and later), you should get [automatic DPI scaling for dialogs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hidpi/high-dpi-desktop-application-development-on-windows#per-monitor-dpi-scaling-support-by-ui-framework--technology). Can you provide a [mcve] with a dialog resource, where this doesn't produce the desired effect on Windows 10 (1703 and later)?

Comment: Do you mean that the dialog box created in the resource editor will become blurred after changing the dpi?

Comment: I mean with I set say 150% and everything gets bigger, the dialog box didn't.  The app is marked as dpi per-monitor aware since the main window and such I handle that.  It's when the dialogbox was opened was same size as it was at 100% dpi.  My surface pro 4 died so waiting for the new 7 with a 4k screen to see how small it is.

Answer (score 0):

[Per-Monitor and Per-Monitor (V2) DPI Awareness:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hidpi/high-dpi-desktop-application-development-on-windows#per-monitor-and-per-monitor-v2-dpi-awareness)

> It is recommended that desktop applications be updated to use
>   per-monitor DPI awareness mode, allowing them to immediately render
>   correctly whenever the DPI changes. **When an application reports to
>   Windows that it wants to run in this mode, Windows will not bitmap
>   stretch the application when the DPI changes, instead sending
>   WM_DPICHANGED to the application window.** It is then the complete
>   responsibility of the application to handle resizing itself for the
>   new DPI. Most UI frameworks used by desktop applications (Windows
>   common controls (comctl32), Windows Forms, Windows Presentation
>   Framework, etc.) do not support automatic DPI scaling, requiring
>   developers to resize and reposition the contents of their windows
>   themselves.

You can resize the dialog box in the `WM_DPICHANGED` message.

```
    case WM_DPICHANGED:
    {
        LPRECT lpRect = (LPRECT)lParam;
        SetWindowPos(hWnd, nullptr, lpRect->left, lpRect->top, lpRect->right - lpRect->left, lpRect->bottom - lpRect->top, SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOACTIVATE);
        return 0;
    }
```

**Updated:**

*For per-monitor DPI, v2 is the only one that can handle the dialog DPI scale., v1 does not so on WIndows 8.1 and older versions of Window 10, it has to be done manually.  Windows 8.1 and older Windows 10, we don't scale controls.  So the solution should be just resize the dialog.  It has to enumerate all controls and resize them during WM_DPICHANGED if the dialog is not resizable.*

Comment: The question was how to do it.  How do you scale an complete dialog based on a resource?  I would think you load it to some memory location, parse some structure tree updating things but not sure.  Seems like a dialog should do it itself.  I know there is a thread level option in Win10, but need to support 8.1.

Comment: @df234987 Yes, you need to manually change the size of the dialog box in the `WM_DPICHANGED` message.

Comment: how do you do that (all contents, no bitmaps exist)?

Comment: It appears someone realized the mistake and created the PerMonitorV2 in Creators Update 1703 to fix the issue with dialog boxes, but that leave Win8.1 to Win10 1607 in limbo with PerMonitor.   Does MS have a provided function to call that will scale for those versions of windows (provide as source code of course)?

Comment: @df234987    I had submitted the request internally, please refer to the updated answer for the reply.

Comment: Thanks, is there an example available how to do: "It has to enumerate all controls and resize them during WM_DPICHANGED"

Comment: @df234987 Find a [sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hidpi/high-dpi-desktop-application-development-on-windows#example) of the button.

Comment: i was hoping for a generic pass the dialog resource and it loaded it, parsed the data, updated it, then display it (without having to know what controls are on there or what there id was).  codeproject had something, just didn't know if MS provided a fully documented way.

Comment: @df234987 Sorry, I didn't find the generic pass the dialog resource you said.